# How do you dynamically call a function in Actionscript 3 from Javascript at runtime without using eval()?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I'm trying to build an API in JS that will perform some operations and then execute the callback that's registered in AS when it's done. Because it's an API, I am just providing a JS method signature for another developer to call in Flash. Thus, the callback name that's registered in the AS part of the code should be a parameter that's passed in to the JS API in order for JS to communicate back to Flash.

For example:

[AS3 code]

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("flashCallbackName", processRequest);
ExternalInterface.call("namespace.jsFnToCall", flashCallbackName);

function processRequest(data:String):void
{
    //do stuff
}
```

[JS code]

```
var namespace =
{
    jsFnToCall: function(callback)
    {
        //Do stuff in this function and then fire the callback when done.

        //getFlashMovie is just a util function that grabs the
        //Flash element via the DOM; assume "flash_id"'s a global var
        //Below does not work...it's what I'd be ideally be doing some how.
        getFlashMovie(flash_id).callback(data);
    }
};
```

Because the definition of the function is in AS, I can't use the window[function name] approach. The only way I can think of is to build the callback in a string and then use the eval() to execute it.

Suggestions? T.I.A.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can think of one thing I would try, and one thing that would work.

What I would try first.

```
getFlashMovie(flash_id)['callback'](data);
```

What would work:  Have the callback always be the same, say `callback`.  The first parameter to the callback could be used to determine what actual function to call in flash.  For example:

```
function callback($fn:String, $data:*) {

    // either
    this[$fn]($data);
    // or
    switch ($fn) {
        case "callback1":
            DoSomeCallback($data);
            break;
}
```

Comment: I'll try suggestion #1 and see if it works. Thanks.

For suggestion #2, I had thought about that, but I didn't want to make it that rigid in terms of structure, and, I think it's harder to enforce that.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally passing the [objectID](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#objectID) makes it a bit simpler:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("flashCallbackName", processRequest);
ExternalInterface.call("namespace.jsFnToCall", ExternalInterface.objectID, "flashCallbackName");
```

Then in your JS:

```
var namespace =
{
  jsFnToCall: function(objectID, callback)
  {
    //Do stuff in this function and then fire the callback when done.

    document[objectID][callback](data);
  }
};
```

Comment: Ah, that's interesting (the objectID). Didn't know that was available. Thanks for the tip!